# Position UIBarbuttonItem to the VERY left

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` that I want hugging the very left of the screen. I've tried putting a fixed `barbutton` with **width=0** before the button and other configurations but there's always several pixels between the button and **x=0**.

I've also tried changing the `imageInset` of the `UIButton`

```
UIButton *moreButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
moreButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 35);
[moreButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Morebutton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
moreButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -8, 0, 8);
[moreButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressedMoreButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *moreBar = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:moreButton] autorelease];
```

But tapping near the edge of the screen doesn't trigger the `selector` (probably because only the image is moved but not the button itself) and increasing the `size` of the button doesn't **affect the gap between the button and the left side**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to put your button to the container view and change position of button on the view.

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
    button.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;       
    button.frame= CGRectMake(-4.0, 0.0, 30, 30);
    [button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIView *v=[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cellTextSize.width+10, buttonImage.size.height)] autorelease];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [v addSubview:button];

    return [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:v] autorelease];
```

Comment: the UIView still doesn't reach the very left so even if i move the button, the touch isn't inside the UIView so it's touch event isn't triggered.

Comment: Could you post any visual information. How it must looks like?